# What does * before a CSS property do?

Tags: css

```
input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}
input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}
```

This is from the YUI reset css.  What does the * before font-size:100% do?

Comment: Like Marc answered below you can prefix things with '*' and '_' to target different versions of IE

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879276/please-explain-in-detail-this-part-of-yui3-css-reset and

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an IE hack. The second line is only correctly parsed and executed by IE 7 and below. See http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-asterisk_prefix for more information.

*Edit:* One remark on using such (invalid!) CSS: **please don't**. There are plenty of ways of keeping your CSS clean of such mess. You'll never know what behavior IE9 might bring. Better to put these kind of hacks in a separate CSS file which can then be included through [conditional comments](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#conditional_comments-css_hack).

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise: IE6/7 [doesn't](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Win_Bugs#Inheritance) support `font-size: inherit`. This hack is supposed to achieve the goal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a hack to make that definition only apply to IE 7 or less while being ignored by other browser as an asterisk is not a legal character before an attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

As already told, those are hack to target specific browsers. Marc's suggestion is quiet right, and here's a link to give you an kick start:

http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks